# How to best draw attention to a potentially better answer (but on a different question)?

Tags: discussion, search

I was looking for an efficient algorithm to generate all unique permutations of sequences with repeated values (in Python).  One of the questions/answers I came across was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284396/permutations-with-unique-values) question.  With an appropriate title of: **"permutations with unique values**,**"** it's easily found when searching.  The accepted answer is perfectly *acceptable*: I wouldn't want to disparage it.

I had however, already come across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12837695/429982) answer to a question, who's title, **"Can this algorithm be improved without recursion**,**"**  wouldn't garner near as much attention.  The accepted answer is a nice python implementation of Knuth's "Algorithm L", and runs in about 1/4 of the time as the accepted, popular answer on the other question.

As we all know, one could rewrite this in C/assembler and make it faster if speed was really important, but given that Stack Overflow is, or at least wants to be, the go-to place for the best answers to questions, I was curious what the best way of drawing attention to this alternate answer was.

Some options:

1. Do nothing.  A casual Stack Overflow search will find the slower algorithm, but too bad.
2. Leave a comment on the popular question (and/or the accepted answer) that an alternative solution existed elsewhere and was faster (not sure how many users seeking answers bother to read all the comments).
3. Change the title of the unpopular question to something better reflecting the actual topic it's asking about (even if the asker didn't realize exactly what they were asking for).  This may help partially, but the other question's popularity lead will probably still get it all the hits.
4. Leave a comment on the less popular answer that he should cross-post his great answer on the other question (I'm not even sure if this behaviour is frowned upon).

Recommendations on the best action to take (if any)?

**Edit:**:  5)  Migrate the (slightly better) answer to the popular question  (was suggested in a comment by @Theolodis...can this be done?)

Comment: I would say 3.... that title is useless

Comment: "he should cross-post his great answer" - That may get automatically reported to moderators. He should probably change it to fit the other question if that option is chosen.

Comment: IMO, do 2 and 3.

Answer (score 8):

Two steps.

First, edit the unpopular question to have a better title.  That is a horrible title.

Change it to actually describe the problem, not the answer.

Next, *mark the popular question as a duplicate of the unpopular question with the better answer*.  Duplicates are about "does the answer answer this question", and in this case the duplicate should go towards the one with the better answer.  Now, it will take 5 people (or one with the Mjölnir) to do this.

Comment: I feel like marking the better formulated question as duplicate of the other one would cost the first some upvotes in the future. But, if you compare the dates, the better formulated question was also the first one to appear. I would personally prefer to maybe migrate the answer to the better question?

Comment: Can we "migrate" an answer? That sounds useful. After (and during the process of) asking this question, I've come to the definite conclusion about changing the title.  I can't really get on board with marking the popular question as a duplicate of the unpopular one though.  The popular question was phrased much better.

Comment: @Gerrat I do not know if we can, what I can say for sure is that *I can't*. But moderators may have the capabilities and/or rights to do so. That's why I did put a question mark, not because I was not sure of what I was saying ;)

Answer (score -10):

## Changing the Way We Present Ourselves Online as Technical Professionals

> WE are more than an expert site.  This ***IS A SITE FOR EXPERTS***.  There is a difference...

When ***I say "expert", that is not a skill-level or years-of-experience assessment...*** it is a statement of something deeper... the mindset of the professional (or hobbyist) involved.

Here is an example from [a recent post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25389417/trying-to-create-an-apex-link-column-that-queries-a-report) I made in response to a very general design concept in Oracle APEX.

(I also don't mind tackling questions that were misunderstood and buried under lots of negative site-karma... if their topic has some utility.)[4]

### Call to Action and Some Good News

Something cool is happening these days.  Try searching anything technical in your field... something general or easy.  I have noticed at least in my arena (Oracle, databases, etc.) posts from Stack Overflow (SO) are guided to the researchers.  It may not be from cross-linking or advertising and marketing.  That's a solid reputation to have online.

You can answer any and all questions across the board, nobody is blocking you. Experts should however, bring *something else* to the table that makes a plain answer an "**expert** answer".

Comment: This is too long...

Comment: I read the whole answer, but still can't figure out what's your answer to OP's question. So what should OP do to give the better answer more visibility?

Comment: Wow.  I can recognize all the effort you've put into this, but it seems as though you're actually making a proposal (on how we improve the way the site works).  I was looking for something a little more specific.

Comment: Can you add a **td;dr**?

Comment: @dav_i it's [tl;dr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Too_long;_didn't_read) :)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Sorry was just a tyqo.

Comment: @Luiggi:  ...or was it...http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=td%3Bdr

Comment: I'm sympathetic of long-winded posts (check out some of mine). But like  user000001, I can't see what this has to do with the question being asked here. It looks like you have some interesting ideas here that would be worth sharing with the community. If you can trim it down a bit (not because I have an objection to its length, but because clearly others don't have a long enough attention span to read the whole thing) and *offer some concrete suggestions*, you might reconsider posting a new question here on Meta.